# Accessing device on wifi1 from wifi2

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

Due to my current house being quite too big, and given my ISP installed my main router quite out of reach of the main and guest room, I used a large CAT5 cable and a spare WAP I had lying around and extended the reach.

I tried setting them up using the same wireless name and credentials, but it didn't work, so I ended up with wifi1 and wifi2

Main router--------------Large Cable----------------------Child router [Wifi1]=================================[Wifi2]

I setup child router as for main router be the only one to assign ip's, and everything works perfectly, except that, if a device is on wifi1, it won't be reachable from a device in wifi2

For example, if I have my pc on wifi1 and my chromecast and mobile on wifi2, I can't access my plex server on my pc. Even though, when checking the device list on the main router, I can see it list pc (192.168.15.5), chromecast (192.168.15.8) and my mobile (192.168.15.9) correctly

Any idea what my issue be. I tried, connecting my laptop to wifi2 and pinging my pc, but it didn't reach out.

For the record, I'm a software developer, with a little knowledge on networking, so I get the hold of several things, but them all

Thanks in advance

Comment: What wireless access point was this?

Comment: In your access point's firmware, you need to set it to Wireless Repeater mode, and you may need to record the MAC address of your main wireless router on a piece of paper in order to configure the AP properly.

Comment: @McDonald's OP only has two network interfaces, a wireless access point, and a router with wireless capabilities

Comment: please provide routing table of both router.
and output of ping command from Laptop To PC.

Comment: Ya, I'm having a hard time visualizing an accurate picture how these are all connected together on the network. (@varfirstName Comment removed)

Comment: @varfirstName He doesn’t want to repeat. He wants to create a dedicated network because “wifi1” is out of range.

Comment: @DanielB No. OP is trying to create one large network with two access points so that devices in different locations on different SSIDs can actually talk.

Comment: Please provide the output of `ping 192.168.15.5` when connected to “wifi2”. If you have an Android phone you could use a terminal emulator to ping.

Comment: @varfirstName is right, this is my objective. Will provide an update when I get home. Thanks all for the help, answers and comments

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you've selected the Access Point (AP) option on your router, which is strangely named Repeater on my DD-WRT router.

What Repeater mode does is deploy a new wireless network from a parent DHCP server that can issue IP addresses as a surrogate. This mode broadcasts a different ESSID in order to avoid conflicts, and is often used with a newer access point attached to an existing router that is only able to broadcast on the congested 2.4GHz wireless band, allowing a legacy device to offer greater wireless throughput.

> Repeater
>
> A) DHCP & NAT enabled
>
> B) Clients on different subnet from primary router.
>
> C) Computers connected to one router cannot see
> computers connected to other routers in Windows Network.

---

What you want is known to me as Repeater (Bridge) mode. What this does is inherit all properties of an existing wireless network and act as if it is effectively your router. Often times it doesn't even appear with its' own IP address, but instead the router's. This can be done through a wired connection to the existing router, or even a wireless one (though you will only achieve the speeds of the existing wireless router or less).

> Repeater Bridge
>
> A) Wireless Repeater capabilities with DHCP & NAT disabled.
>
> B) Clients on the same subnet as primary router.
>
> C) All computers can see one another in Windows Network.

---

You can most likely look in the manual that came with your WAP or one provided by the manufacturer online.

### So here's the big issue

#### The problem you're experiencing might not be a mode issue that I described above, AT ALL.

The terms that your router's manufacturer use may be incorrect. My router is configured with DD-WRT, which misuses the terms and distorts the original definition of them. Your manual may something wildly different from mine. I only have experience with this on a child router with DD-WRT firmware. I didn't need to manually reconfigure DHCP or anything. It just *worked*. (Mine are on two different subnets btw, so they have the same restriction you have right now.)

**Your router may be WILDLY different**.

Here is an explanation of what you probably want to do (on DD-WRT, which should be very similar for your router):

> If you want to connect two routers with an ethernet cable, so that all devices connected to either of them can communicate with each other, plug an ethernet cable into the LAN (Not WAN) port of each router, set the IP to the second router to the same LAN IP address as the first router PLUS ONE (eg. 192.168.1.2), disable dhcp on the second router, and set it to a different channel as the first.
>
> -[Source](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Access_Point)

[Here's TP-Link defining the term "Access Point"](http://www.tp-link.com/us/faq-1143.html)

[Here's a tutorial for NETGEAR's WPN802 AP configured in Wireless Repeater mode.](https://kb.netgear.com/215/Configuring-wireless-repeating-with-a-WPN802-access-point)

[Here's an explanation of this on the firmware which I'm using this on right now.](https://neverendingsecurity.wordpress.com/2015/03/18/what-is-the-difference-between-client-bridge-wireless-repeater-modes-in-dd-wrt/)

Comment: I beg to differ. AP mode is *exactly* what he needs, because that’s the way to go when you have multiple access points connected by Ethernet. Repeater mode is inferior because it relies on a wireless connection to other router(s).

Comment: What “WLAN port” might you be referring to?

Comment: I made a typo: "WAN" port. It's used for receiving network access from another source. On switches, this is known as the uplink port.

Comment: You simply plug one end into the child's WAN port, and the other into the parent's LAN Ethernet port.

Comment: You wouldn’t use the WAN port when using a router as an access point. Instead, the general steps are: Adjust IP address, turn of DHCP, set up wireless network, connect uplink to *LAN* port. That way you get a single broadcast domain.

Comment: Uplink is the WAN port on the child router...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64008/discussion-between-daniel-b-and-var-firstname).

Comment: I'm not sure whether to downvote this or not. For some device models, it may be completely true. Yet, for the majority of "standalone" APs, it's utterly wrong... The problem with your 2nd paragraph is that some devices use the term "AP mode" in really confusing / different ways (sometimes even having the opposite meaning than usual), so you've got to be careful with broad statements. Same with terms like "router" or "repeater", sadly.

Comment: @grawity I mean Repeater Bridge mode. My DD-WRT router works perfectly fine with this setup. It's about 20m away from the main router and gives the gigabit speed I pay for. The existing router could deliver a fraction of that speed at the distance at which I use it.

Comment: I've noticed that "repeater" is again used in several different ways... Previously it meant literally receiving and re-sending the same signal (which _ruins_ performance). Nowadays I've seen it used to describe wired bridges (APs)... If your DD-WRT gets its own Internet connection via wired LAN, it's not a repeater; it's an AP in the original sense – even if the DD-WRT devs decided to swap the terms around.

Comment: @grawity I'm going to upvote you because you have clarified that my use of the term is correct in context of the DD-WRT firmware, and respectfully told me that I'm misinformed.

Comment: It might very well be just the language changing naturally, and/or manufacturers trying to make the options more understandable, but it sure as hell makes things confusing and inconsistent... If popular firmware like DD-WRT uses this terminology, then it's very possible that OP has been caught in the trap you describe.